# Hive CLI not starting

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

I’m trying to run Hive client from Linux box(Separate from Hadoop cluster nodes) but when I start Hive CLI from command I get below error. Can somebody please suggest ? I’m not getting anything relevant on internet.

```
>hive
WARNING: Use "yarn jar" to launch YARN applications.

Logging initialized using configuration in file:/etc/hive/2.3.0.0-2525/0/hive-log4j.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1436575073312_0041 to YARN : Failed to renew token: Kind: TIMELINE_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 10.25.100.118:8188, Ident: (owner=hduser, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1436827743392, maxDate=1437432543392, sequenceNumber=36, masterKeyId=16)
       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:535)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:677)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:621)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezException: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1436575073312_0041 to YARN : Failed to renew token: Kind: TIMELINE_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 10.25.100.118:8188, Ident: (owner=hduser, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1436827743392, maxDate=1437432543392, sequenceNumber=36, masterKeyId=16)
        at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.start(TezClient.java:370)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:184)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.open(TezSessionState.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:532)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnException: Failed to submit application_1436575073312_0041 to YARN : Failed to renew token: Kind: TIMELINE_DELEGATION_TOKEN, Service: 10.25.100.118:8188, Ident: (owner=hduser, renewer=yarn, realUser=, issueDate=1436827743392, maxDate=1437432543392, sequenceNumber=36, masterKeyId=16)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.submitApplication(YarnClientImpl.java:271)
        at org.apache.tez.client.TezYarnClient.submitApplication(TezYarnClient.java:72)
        at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.start(TezClient.java:365)
```

Comment: If your cluster uses Kerberos authentication then it could be related to an issue in DNS vs. hosts file, sthg like http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/yarn-and-kerberos-issue/

Answer (score 0):

Its a kerberos authenticated cluster and the credentials provided are not authenticated to use hive